# Unknown type name 'Tester' when trying to use swift class inside objective-c file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to use a swift class in a an objective-c file, but I am met with the error `Unknown type name 'Tester'` below is a snippet of my swift code:

```
import Foundation

class Tester{
  var studentname: String = ""
  var mark: Int = 0
  var mark2: Int = 0
}
```

and here is my objective-c code that is intended to use the swift class:

```
#import "Stringator.h"
#import "reactnativeios-Swift.h"


@interface Stringator()
@property (nonatomic, strong) Tester *tester;
@end


@implementation Stringator

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(greetings:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback){

  NSString* someString = _tester.studentname;

  callback(@[someString]);
}

@end
```

According to the error I get, it seems that objective-c cannot find my Tester class, how do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add `@objc` before class name and make it subclass of `NSObject`. Hence it will visible on Objective-C. After changing your code clean build folder so it will re-generate `reactnativeios-Swift.h`.

```
import Foundation

@objc class Tester: NSObject
{
  @objc var studentname: String = ""
  @objc var mark: Int = 0
  @objc var mark2: Int = 0
}
```

You can access `Tester` and as below,

```
Tester *tester = [[Tester alloc]init];
tester.studentname = @"John";
```

Comment: how do I now use the Tester class in my objective-c,   presently based on how I use it above it throws an error that says `Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type` and `Unknown type name 'Tester'`

Comment: calling a property like _tester.studentname; gives me an error of `Property 'studentname' not found on object of type 'Tester *'`

Comment: You can add `@objc` at variable declaration also, So it will be available in Objective-C Class. @Oto-ObongEshiett